# Including styles for vaadin-combo-box-item

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am trying to add flag icons in a Vaadin Flow Combobox using a customer `ComponentRenderer`:

```
new ComponentRenderer<>(locale -> {
            HorizontalLayout item = new HorizontalLayout();
            item.setDefaultVerticalComponentAlignment(FlexComponent.Alignment.BASELINE);

            Span langIcon = new Span();
            langIcon.addClassNames("flag-icon", "flag-icon-" + getTranslation("App.Language.Flag", locale));
            item.add(langIcon);

            item.add(new Span(locale.getDisplayLanguage(locale)));

            return item;
        });
```

The icons come from *flag-icon-css* (see [here](https://github.com/lipis/flag-icon-css)) included via gradle compile dependency "org.webjars.bowergithub.lipis:flag-icon-css:3.3.0" and annotation `@StyleSheet("frontend://bower_components/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.min.css")` on my main layout class. In a different place with `ListBox` component, icons are shown as expected. However, when used via `ComponentRenderer` in a combobox nothing shows up.

Inspecting the HTML, I see that the `<vaadin-combo-box-item>` within ComboBox renders everything under its shadow root in contrast to `<vaadin-item>` within ListBox which renders it as `<slot>`. **Why is that? And how could I use the flag icon CSS styles in combo box items?**

Comment: Filed an issue on github: https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-combo-box-flow/issues/244

Comment: There is a workaround available in the issue comments.